# Internal Only Home PBX Intercom Using Vintage Wired Phones

Tags: telephone

I would like to set up a home PBX that is INTERNAL only.  All of the other tutorials I see include an element of hooking to an outside line.  I assume this is to draw the power needed.

I would like to be able to pick up the phone in a room, dial a number (a one or two digit number) and have it ring a specific phone in another part of the house.  I understand this would need to be some sort of PBX, but again, I want it to be internal only.  I don't want to be able to dial to an outside line and I don't have or want landline service.

Any ideas on equipment needed?

Comment: This is more of a shopping question and as such would be off topic, the ability to hear on phone hand sets is easy but dialing is not.

Comment: Look for a Panasonic hybrid system used on eBay etc. Works with ordinary phones or special Panasonic phones. Intercom. Hold. Etc

Comment: manassehkatz-Moving 2 Codidact  Thank you for the great answer.

Comment: Ed Beal, I don't understand why you typed anything at all.  Basically you offered no answer but instead just made a comment on why you thought the question was dumb.  Not helpful at all.   You can always take a pass if you think a question is dumb.

Comment: This question may be better suited for the “Internet of things stack exchange” I did some research on using my old rotary dial phones for alternative purposes. There are geeks out there that know how to repurpose them. Geek, is a term of endearment for me not an insult.

Answer (score 2):

> I assume this is to draw the power needed.

Incorrect. A PBX is usually independently powered. Most people who install a PBX want to be able to call outside numbers.

RCA makes a PBX-style set of phones that operate over shared wiring common in a household. See https://www.rca4business.com/4linephones

Comment: Thanks so much for your helpful answer.